# rename an association in has_many

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have model Course and model CourseUnitRole.

a course has many course unit roles.

I defined:

```
has_many :course_unit_roles
```

So course.course_unit_roles gives me all what I need.

But I would like to change the association to: course.unit_roles.

I tried to add:

```
has_many :unit_roles, :through => :course_unit_roles
```

but it gives me an error.

Where is the problem?

Comment: try `has_many :unit_roles, class: CourseUnitRole`

Comment: Should be class_name. Thx

Answer (score 5):

To rename `has_many` feature just, rename its name, but also you should implicitly specify class name of the record to perform interaction with. So:

```
has_many :unit_roles, class_name: :CourseUnitRole
```

Comment: It should be `has_many :unit_roles, class_name: 'CourseUnitRole'`

Comment: the key is `class:` should be `class_name:`